# How do I style my ListViewItems to not have rounded corners and also have it so that selected items have their background colors inverted?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, styling

Say I have the following code (you can create a new WPF project and test this out, just give the default Grid the name MainGrid):

```
namespace WPFTesting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        ObservableCollection<Message> messages = new ObservableCollection<Message>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a test."));
            messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a multi-line message.\nThis is a multi-line message."));
            messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a multi-line message.\nThis is a multi-line message."));
            messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a multi-line message.\nThis is a multi-line message."));
            messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a test."));
            messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a test."));
            messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a test."));
            messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a test."));
            ListView listView = new ListView();
            Style style = new Style();
            style.TargetType = typeof(ListViewItem);
            DataTrigger trigger = new DataTrigger();
            trigger.Binding = new Binding("Text");
            trigger.Value = "This is a test.";
            trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListViewItem.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Pink));
            style.Triggers.Add(trigger);
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListViewItem.HeightProperty, 20.0));
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListViewItem.MarginProperty, new Thickness(0)));
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListViewItem.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(0)));
            listView.ItemContainerStyle = style;
            GridView gridView = new GridView();
            listView.View = gridView;
            GridViewColumn timeStampColumn = new GridViewColumn();
            timeStampColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Date");
            GridViewColumnHeader timeStampHeader = new GridViewColumnHeader();
            timeStampHeader.Content = "Time";
            timeStampColumn.Header = timeStampHeader;
            gridView.Columns.Add(timeStampColumn);
            GridViewColumn messageColumn = CreateGridViewColumn("Message", "Text");
            gridView.Columns.Add(messageColumn);
            Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.Source = messages;
            listView.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
            MainGrid.Children.Add(listView);
        }

        private static GridViewColumn CreateGridViewColumn(string header, string bindingPath)
        {
            GridViewColumn gridViewColumn = new GridViewColumn();
            gridViewColumn.Header = new GridViewColumnHeader() { Content = header };
            string xaml = @"
            <DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml""> 
              <StackPanel Orientation=""Horizontal"">
                <TextBlock Text=""{Binding Text}"" MaxHeight=""20"">
                  <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                    <TextBlock Text=""{Binding Text}""/>
                  </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                </TextBlock>
              </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>";
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xaml);
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
            gridViewColumn.CellTemplate = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as DataTemplate;

            return gridViewColumn;
        }

        public class Message
        {

            public Message(DateTime aDate, String aText)
            {
                Date = aDate;
                Text = aText;
            }

            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public String Text { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice between pink lines, ListViewItems have a slight corner roundedness. How can I remove this effect?

Also, row selection isn't all that obvious because I removed border thickness. How can I make row selection more obvious? I was thinking about inverting the background color, but that might not be such a good idea, or perhaps adding a brush with a certain transparency on it? I'm not entirely sure how to do this, could someone please show me?

Comment: An irrelevant question: Why do you use the code-behind to apply styles to your control? That is exactly why XAML is created.

Comment: No problem. The third party control I'm using requires me to dynamically add elements to it, and so I can't mark them up, otherwise, trust me, I would! My example is the simplest case; this is all part of a much larger solution. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override that `Style` by creating a new `ControlTemplate` for the `ListViewItem`. This is a lot of work as it will require you to redefine all the `VisualStates`, `Triggers` etc.

I have included enough code to demonstrate the process in code behind and this will remove the rounded border. I will leave it for you to add the `VisualStates` if you want to go down this route.

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a test."));
        messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a multi-line message.\nThis is a multi-line message."));
        messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a multi-line message.\nThis is a multi-line message."));
        messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a multi-line message.\nThis is a multi-line message."));
        messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a test."));
        messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a test."));
        messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a test."));
        messages.Add(new Message(DateTime.Now, "This is a test."));
        ListView listView = new ListView();
        CreateListViewItemStyle(listView);
        GridView gridView = new GridView();
        listView.View = gridView;
        GridViewColumn timeStampColumn = new GridViewColumn();
        timeStampColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Date");
        GridViewColumnHeader timeStampHeader = new GridViewColumnHeader();
        timeStampHeader.Content = "Time";
        timeStampColumn.Header = timeStampHeader;
        gridView.Columns.Add(timeStampColumn);
        GridViewColumn messageColumn = CreateGridViewColumn("Message", "Text");
        gridView.Columns.Add(messageColumn);
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = messages;
        listView.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
        MainGrid.Children.Add(listView);
    }

    private static void CreateListViewItemStyle(ListView listView)
    {
        string xaml = @"
        <Style  xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"" TargetType=""ListViewItem"">
            <Setter Property=""Height"" Value=""20""/>
            <Setter Property=""Template"">
                <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType=""{x:Type ListViewItem}"">
                    <Border Background=""{TemplateBinding Background}""
                            CornerRadius=""0"">
                        <GridViewRowPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding=""{Binding Text}"" Value=""This is a test."">
                    <Setter Property=""Background"" Value=""Pink""/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>";
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xaml);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        listView.ItemContainerStyle = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as Style;
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for! Question for you, how did you know you had to set the CornerRadius to 0? Did you get the ControlTemplate from the default style applied to it by Microsoft's framework?

Comment: When you define a ControlTemplate you are essentially styling the control from scratch (hence why all VisualStates no longer work). You could actually remove the 'CornerRadius="0"' line and it will still work. I only added it for clarity as that is the property that causes the rounding in the default template.

Answer (score 1):

try and see following XAML coding. Use Datagrid instead ListView.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                        Value="ExtraBold" />
                <Setter Property="Height"
                        Value="20" />
            </Trigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text}" Value="This is a test.">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" />

    <DataGrid Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MainGrid1"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          AlternationCount="2"
          FrozenColumnCount="2">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date}"
                            Header="Time" Width="Auto" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Text}"
                            Header="Message" Width="*" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

At the end of constructor of the MainWindow, add following last line

```
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = messages;
        listView.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
        MainGrid.Children.Add(listView);

        MainGrid1.ItemsSource = messages;
```

You may need to write multitrigger to check text value and mouse over and then change the appropriate background color.

Comment: This would work, and your solution is awesome. I really appreciate the work you did here, but sadly, I must use a ListView, because all the development work has already been done using this object, and it is far too late to switch to a DataGrid. Is there no way to style the ListView and have it work? There must be a way.

Answer (score 0):

When applying your style to a ListView directly it seems to work as you want.  I believe the rounded style is being forced upon the items by the GridView that you are using as the View of the ListView.

I would suggest considering a different collection of controls to display your items if possible.

Comment: There must be a way to override that style.